# Grails GORM - Find all objects with distinct property value

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, grails-orm, distinct

I'm using Grails and I'm trying to figure out how to get all the distinct values of a domain class' property.  In other words I'm looking for all the distinct values for a column.  However, I'm not sure how to translate this into a GORM statement, preferable a criteria statement.

I'm open to either something that gives me a list of domain classes (with each having a distinct value for the property in question) and I collect all the properties values.  Or something that gives me the distinct property values directly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think all you need to accomplish this is to use `projections` and `distinct`. According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) this will provide you with a list of distinct values of a property from your domain class.

```
def results = MyDomain.withCriteria {
  projections {
    distinct("theDistinctProperty")
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question is "Find all objects with distinct property value" not "Find all distinct properties of list of objects".

Comment: It does do exactly what is asked "all the distinct values for a column" that quote is from the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use criteria projections and groupProperty in order to get distinct values i share this code is working in production right now

```
def criteria = Item.createCriteria()
    def items = criteria {
      projections {
        groupProperty "product", "product"
      }

      order "product"
      //remeber import import org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer in order to get alias property
      resultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
    }
```